# Change image onClick with Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three toggle "Image Buttons" within a button group on my HTML page

Initially all three buttons will show the black and white versions of their associated images.

When the user clicks on a particular image button, I want to display a colour version of the associated image.

Only one of the buttons should display a colour image at any one time.

If the user subsequently clicks on a different image button
The first image button clicked must reset its image back to the black and white version and the newly clicked on image button must display its colour image.

Heres as far as I have got displaying my three image buttons

```
<div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <img id="riddler-img" src="images/2754.png" />
                        <img id="unhappy-img" src="images/1f621.png" class="hidden"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <img id="riddler-img" src="images/2754.png" />
                        <img id="neutral-img" src="images/1f610.png"  class="hidden"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                        <img id="riddler-img" src="images/2754.png" />
                        <img id="happy-img" src="images/1f600.png" class="hidden" />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired effect without employing javascript?